# In C++, is it possible to provide a parameter to an overloaded operator via use of template of otherwise?

Tags: c++

For example, can I have a statement like the following:

```
A = B *<5> C;
```

where 5 is a parameter (that can provide context), * is an overloaded operator and and operator* uses the given parameter.

For example, A NON-WORKING and not very meaningful (just to show the point) code is listed below.

(It is of course possible if we define a new function *mul* i.o. overloading the existing * operator.)

```
struct myClass {
   int val = 0;
   myClass (int x) {
      val = x;
   }

   template<int s> myClass operator* (myClass x) {
        return val * x.val + s;
   };
};

int main()
{
   myClass a(10), b(3);
   myClass c = a *<5> b;
}
```

==== EDIT ====

I would like to add some motivation in hope to better explain the question:

meta-programming in general provides a way to extend the language.
When a compiler sees an expression C = A * B, it knows A, and B, of course, but it also knows where the result is going, in this case C, and can act on this knowledge to provide a better code.

When overloading an operator, we only have A, B - providing some information about the result, for example the type of C can, in some cases, provide better optimization and for my original case avoid completely erroneous result.

The reason for wanting something like *<5> is that the parameter can be made optional and only be used when needed, and when not needed - it is the normal *.

Using: c =  a.operator* b; as suggested below works and solves the problem.

Comment: XY problem. Use a named function.

Comment: The whole point of overloading operators is to use the syntax of the existing operator. This would violate this. You should just use a normal template method.

Comment: If your concern is based on the return type, you could consider returning a proxy that dispatches based on which `Proxy::operator T()` is called.

Answer (score 5):

In order to be able to specify the template parameter you need to switch to member function call syntax.  That would turn

```
myClass c = a *<5> b;
```

into

```
myClass c = a.operator*<5>(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of one workaround that allows you to keep normal operator syntax and still tunnel in an extra argument:

- wrap (a reference to) the left-hand-side in a type with its own `operator*`

So your call site would look something like

```
A = wrapper<5>(B) * C;
```

where `wrapper` is something like `std::reference_wrapper` with an `operator*` returning ... whatever `B * C` is.

This looks so clunky that it honestly doesn't feel worthwhile. I guess it could forward to the templated member `operator*` from Nathan's answer if you want.

Comment: Or `B.with<5>() * C` if you want a spelling where the 5 appears in the middle